# \newcommand with two options: omit vs. leave empty

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments

I am re-writing our template for exams, and I would like to create a command `\questionpart{Q}{A}` which I can set up in a way, so that I can turn the solutions on and off, and also format und number them automatically and the such.

I also would like to have a version `\questionpart{Q}` which ONLY creates the question, without the solution environment.

Now, for some reason, I can get the desired output writing `\questionpart{Q}{}`, but not `\questionpart{Q}`. Why is that so? And how could I make my command behave the way I like?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{ifthen}

    \newcommand\test[2]{
        #1
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}
            {}
            {XXX: #2}
    }

    \begin{document}
        \test{question}{solution}

        \test{question without solution}

        \test{question with empty solution}{}
    \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: If you van come up with a more meaningful title, feel free to change it.

Comment: if the argument is optional it should be in `[]` not `{}` but then `\newcommand` can only define optional arguments as the first command. As you have it `#2` is the `\par` which is the blank line which does not test equal to `{}`

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but maybe look into packages like `exercise`, they can do this out of the box

Comment: Do you know https://ctan.org/topic/exam and https://ctan.org/topic/exercise

Answer (score 1):

You *could* define `\questionpart` to behave differently if followed by one or two braced groups:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\questionpart}{+m +g}{%
  \formatquestion{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\formatanswer{#2}}%
}
```

where `\formatquestion` and `\formatanswer` will be responsible for formatting the two parts.

This way you will get different results from

```
\questionpart{Q}{A}
\questionpart{Q}
\questionpart{Q}{}
```

Not that I recommend this: a command should have a well defined syntax and using optional braced arguments is against all LaTeX normal conventions.

With a more standard

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\questionpart}{+m +o}{%
  \formatquestion{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\formatanswer{#2}}%
}
```

the syntax would be

```
\questionpart{Q}[A]
\questionpart{Q}
\questionpart{Q}[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if your solution contains square brackets, they must be grouped.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand\test[1]{\def\savetestarg{#1}\testaux}
\newcommand\testaux[1][\TestAux]{\savetestarg\ifx\TestAux#1\relax\else: (#1)\fi}
\begin{document}
\test{question}[solution]

\test{question}[s{[o]}lution containing square brackets]

\test{question without solution}

\test{question with empty solution}[]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments!

I didn't know about the `exercise` package, but I think I can not use it. The same goes for the `xparse` package. The reason is quite simple - I work with lots of other people, who can use Latex, but would never be able to understand that code, in case they need to change something.

Luckily, the comment by David Carlisle (No idea how to link people), actually solved my problem. I just have to replace `\equal{#2}{}` by `\equal{#2}{\par}`, and it works as intended. Thanks a lot!

Here is the working code, with a screenshot from the original document, where you can see all 3 options:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{ifthen}

    \newcommand\test[2]{
        #1
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\par}} % Inserted \par here
            {\par} % For some reason the linebreak disappeared, so I reinserted it
            {XXX: #2}
    }

    \begin{document}
        \test{question}{solution}

        \test{question without solution}

        \test{question with empty solution}{}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with no empty line in between.

Comment: It seems that `\equal{#2}{\par}` doesn't play well with equations :/ So I just leave everything be as it is. Well, at least I learned some things :D